# Install zip module on php 8.2 amazon linux elastic beanstalk

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, pecl

I'm pretty sure the zip extension was included by default in the amazon managed php elb image.

The usual way to do this was adding a config file like this to .ebextensions

```
packages:
    yum:
        php-zip70: []
```

However that doesn't work anymore.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@asdfasdfsdfga gave some good hints. A more modern approach:

Add the file .platform/hooks/prebuild/install-php-zip.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

yum -y install libzip libzip-devel

# Will enable zip extension in /etc/php.ini
pecl upgrade zip
```

Note that "pecl **install** zip" will return an error code if already installed (?!), resulting in your deployment failing the second time you attempt to deploy. Instead, use **upgrade**, which will install if not already installed, and complete successfully if already installed.

The pecl command will insert 'extension="zip.so"' at the top of /etc/php.ini.

Comment: Thank you! the main issue is indeed pecl install zip will throw an error halting the deployment, but your solution is using the newer platform hooks instead of .ebextensions so kudos for that! :)

Comment: Helped me as well. I was also using .ebextentions, Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution I ended up with.

if `test` returns true then run `command`

```
files:
  "/etc/php.d/20-zip.ini":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      extension=zip.so
commands:
  01_install_libzip:
    command: "dnf -y install libzip libzip-devel"
  02_install_zip:
    test: "php -r \"exit(extension_loaded('zip') ? 1 : 0);\""
    command: "pecl install zip"
```

Answer (score 1):

This seemed to work for me as of 08/17/23

Add a config file like this to .ebextensions

*EDIT* Seems like the install commands can only be ran 1 time, otherwise there will be an error that kills the eb deploy because the module is already installed. Working on a more robust solution

```
files:
  "/etc/php.d/98_zip.ini":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      extension=zip.so
commands:
  01_remove_old_config:
    command: "rm -f /etc/php.d/98_zip.ini.bak"
  02_install_stuff:
    command: "dnf -y install libzip libzip-devel"
  03_install_more_stuff:
    command: "pecl install zip"
```

Comment: Use "pecl upgrade" instead of "pecl install" to avoid the error you referenced. This will install the module if not already installed, and exit successfully instead of with an error if already installed.

Comment: can I install PHP IMAP? it is impossible

Comment: Using "pecl upgrade zip" could be tempting but if your application has traffic it will throw a Segmentation Fault error during some of your deployments, it was a hit-and-miss, so it took me a while to find this was the reason. Better to use the other method where you test if it is installed or not.